# I can't replace \xe2\x97\x8f in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, special-characters

It's a bullet character. I want to replace it but keep failing. Why is that?

```
text = text.replace(u"\xe2\x97\x8f", "-")
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that `u"\xe2\x97\x8f"` is the 3 unicode characters U+00E2, U+0097, U+0089 and **not** `"\xe2\x97\x8f".decode("utf-8")`, the latter being indeed u"\u25cf".

Answer (score 1):

It works when I replace it using another character version

```
text = text.replace(u"\u25cf", "-")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because "\xe2\x97\x8f" is a byte sequence instead of a string. Use `b"\xe2\x97\x8f".decode("utf-8")` instead of `u"\xe2\x97\x8f"`.